# How to specify read only text or label in an XML data schema

Tags: xsd, smartgwt

I am referring to XML data schema as detailed here: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp.

When I retrieve data from the database and submit it to the client, there are text fields which I wish to retain as uneditable display/read only fields.

For example, hypothetically in the following sequence,

```
<xsd:element ....
<xsd:element name="employeeName" xsd:type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="projID" xsd:type="xsd:string" readOnly='true'>
<xsd:element name="hireDate" type="xsd:date"/>
<xsd:element ....
<xsd:element name="today" type="xsd:date" readOnly='true'/>
<xsd:element ....
```

Where the client display would interpret the xsd stream and construct the input form.
Of course, the label is faux schema tag to illustrate my need of placing a read-only field in the midst of the form.

In the above example, projID and today should be presented to the user as read-only fields, but there is no such schema syntax as readOnly.

One way I know how to achieve this is to break the stream into two complex type segments and so split it into two input forms and get the  client to present an intervening label in between the two forms.

However, that is problematic because

1. I have quite a few read-only info
   fields that need to be presented
   thro the ui. There would be too many
   interruptions to a smooth single
   form. It's best to have just one input form.
2. Some read-only fields are
   presented in the middle of an entity
   sequence. That means interrupting
   the database-to-jdo(or
   jpa)-to-client data flow for that entity.

Therefore, how to specify a read-only field element in an xml schema?

... and (*sheepishly*) may I ask, how to specify a hidden field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [XML Schema annotations](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_annotation.asp) to provide such information for your application. It's awkward, but it could work.
Something along the lines of:

```
<xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <readOnly>true</readOnly>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
 </xs:element>
```